# Не видит звуковую карту Rasbian (Rasberry Pi 3B+) HDMI

Tags: linux, debian, аудио, pulseaudio, alsa

Каким то способом 'отключил' звуковую карту на Rasbian RasberryPi 3B+, выход звука осуществляется через HDMI, раньше всё работало хорошо, но после настройки выхода звука через микро джек пакетом PulseAudio cmus, теперь звук воспроизводится только через микро джек

Comment: подобные отключения обычно делаются в файле `/boot/config.txt`, а описание параметров находится в файле `/boot/overlays/README`, но может быть и в `/etc/rc*.d`, что-то добавлено

Comment: Проблему решил удалением pulseaudio
Все настройки были в норме

Comment: если покапаться в pulseaudio.deb, то там должны быть скрипты, которые это дело включают и выключают